# Hive query conditional statement in same select query

Tags: sql, hive, conditional-statements, case, hiveql

Is there a way to get in one single hive query to do a if-else kind of setup.

In the my data below I want to ensure that if Model is empty or having '-' I populate the Final column with Device else it should be populated with Model

```
My data is something like this 

Device  Model 
iPhone  6SPlus  
Samsung -
```

```
Output I want is 
Device  Model   Final
iPhone  6SPlus  6SPlus
Samsung -      Samsung
```

```
I am trying a case statement like this but this isn't working.
CASE
       select Device,Model,length(Model) <3 then Device as Final
       else select Device,Model,Model as Final
END
```

Can someone please help here.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi this is about hive implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [CASE operator syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions).

```
select device, model, 
       case when length(model) <3 then Device else model end as Final
  from my_table;
```